# Order By custom order in object inside property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to sort an array of objects by a property of a sub-object:

```
foo = [
  {
    bar: {
      order: "hello" 
    } 
  },
  {
    bar: {
      order: "something" 
    } 
  },
  {
    bar: {
      order: "else" 
    } 
  },
]
```

If I want the order of the `foo` objects to based on a custom order (not alphabetical!) set by `order` values like

`{ "something": 1, "hello": 2, "else": 3 }`

with something like `_orderBy(foo, indexOfMyCustomOrder, 'desc')`, how can I achieve this? Or do I need to separate this logic into two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `indexOfMyCustomOrder` as follows:

```
const indexOfMyCustomOrder = o => order[o.bar.order];
```

... where the `order` variable should be the object that defines the sequence for each possible value of the `order` property.

See snippet:

```js
const foo = [{bar:{order:"hello"}},{bar:{order: "something"}},{bar:{order:"else"}}];
const order = { "something": 1, "hello": 2, "else": 3 };

const result = _.orderBy(foo, o => order[o.bar.order]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if the order is not alphabetical?
Like, `{ "hello": 1, "something": 2, "else": 3 }`, since other objects will also have these values. I will update my question

Comment: OK, updated my answer accordingly. Of course, with such an object you don't really need `desc` as you would define the order with those numbers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
const foo = [{ bar: { order: "hello" } }, { bar: { order: "something" } }, { bar: { order: "else" } } ]
let order = { something: 0, hello: 1, ["else"]: 2 }

console.log(_.orderBy(foo, x => order[x.bar.order]))
console.log(_.orderBy(foo, x => order[x.bar.order], 'desc'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Where you defined your order by `index` map and use that to filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without lodash using a function, where you get the keys of your custom order, you sort them based on their value and the mode (desc or asc) and then reduce that, filtering the array you want ordered adding each time the elements. Hope this helps.

```js
const foo = [{
    bar: {
      order: "hello" 
    } 
  },{
    bar: {
      order: "something" 
    } 
  },{
    bar: {
      order: "else" 
    } 
  },{
    bar: {
      order: "else" 
    } 
  },{
    bar: {
      order: "anotherelse" 
    } 
  }];

const order = { "something": 1, "hello": 3, "else": 2, "missing": 4, "anotherelse": 2 };

const orderWith = (array, order, desc) => 
    Object.keys(order)
          .sort((a, b) => desc ? order[b] - order[a] : order[a] - order[b])
          .reduce((acc, val) => 
              acc.concat(array.filter(({ bar: { order }}) => val === order))
          , []);

console.log('Descending order');
console.log(orderWith(foo, order));

console.log('Ascending order')
console.log(orderWith(foo, order, true));
```